# how to bind methods to (nested) numpy dtype?

Tags: arrays, object, numpy, record

I am wishing to associate object methods with dtypes in a numpy structured array.  That is the underlying object instance state of my collection of object is already packed into a numpy (nested dtype) record_arrays..
   I already have a set of Python objects, that are constructed on top of views of these numpy structured array dtypes that then operate on this underlying continuously packed object instance data.
   That is: I am wishing to use object oriented programming methods, while working with the underlying instance state in it's native packed, structured format.
 ->  Currently working with these numpy structured arrays using Python object methods, requires that explicitly instantiate a Python object on top of it's associated array view each time I re-reference it within the array..
   Might it be possible to more directly associate object methods with a numpy structured array (nested) dtype, so that one could avoid having to reconstruct the object instance each time ??

Answer (score 2):

Your description is confusing.  Some basic code might help make it clearer.  But I'll throw out some possibly relevant observations.

A `numpy` array has a (large) continuous data buffer (flat list of bytes), which it divides into 'records'.  'shape' and 'strides' are used to step through the records.  'dtype' determines how it 'views' each record.

While these arrays are a Python object type, and `dtype` is also a class, in general numpy programmers don't put a lot of effort into constructing added array object classes.  The arrays may be attributes of larger objects (dictionaries, lists, tuples, or custom classes).

`matrix` and `masked_arrays` are examples of subclassing `ndarray`. I have not seen many user defined subclasses; in part because the amount of work to make them fully functional isn't worth it.  `recarray` is a subclass that allows you to access fields of a structured array with attribute syntax.  It may be worth looking at its '**getattr**` method.  Getting general array operations to return the correct array class or subclass is a bit tricky.

`np.lib.index_tricks` defines a few classes that let you use indexing syntax inplace of function syntax (ie. they define custom `__getitem__` methods).

I am not aware of ways to subclass `dtype`.  The most general base dtype is 'object'.  That just stores a pointer to a Python object that is stored elsewhere.  That pointer can point to anything - a number, None, a list, another array, etc. In structured arrays, `dtype` is a compound type, consisting of 'list' of sub-dtypes (which may be nested). But ultimately the structured dtype consists of multiple basic dtypes (ints, floats, strings, object).